# How to share the same recipe for multiple pattern rules in Make?

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have rules like this:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo/%.x: bar/$$*$$(suffix $$@)
    {complicated recipe}
foo/%.y: bar/$$*$$(suffix $$@)
    {complicated recipe}
```

The recipes are exactly the same, so I want to share them.
But this doesn't do the same thing, which doesn't make sense to me:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
foo/%.x foo/%.y: bar/$$*$$(suffix $$@)
    {complicated recipe}
```

What's the correct way to share the same complicated recipe for multiple pattern rules?

Comment: `MACRO = complicated recipe`; then use `${MACRO}` (or `$(MACRO)`) after the two rules.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: I have to use a macro? There's no other way? (I can't do it in 1 line either, so I can't use that syntax.)

Comment: That's my "30-second don't even think about it" solution.  Whether there are alternatives is open to debate — I expect there are, but I'm meant to be asleep and therefore am not thinking clearly.  It's also why it's a comment, not an answer.  There are a bunch of gotchas pending with extensive use of `$$` because of the macro, and so on.  If the recipe is really complex, why isn't it a self-contained script that can be invoked as if it was a compiler?  Make works well when you've got simple compilers which take control arguments to direct their behaviour.

Comment: Since you're already depending on GNU `make` extensions, you could probably implement @JonathanLeffler's suggestion with the help of its `$(eval)` function to work around the fact that your recipe is multi-line.  Or, even simpler, you can probably change it into a single-line recipe by replacing the newlines with semicolons.

Comment: FWIW, I too am surprised that the attempt presented in the question did not work, but I haven't time at the moment to investigate whether that's because of the double expansion, because of some characteristic of pattern rules, or both.  Or something else.

Comment: @JohnBollinger: I thought about making it a script (and I might still do that) but then I'd still have to duplicate the calls to the script. Ideally I wouldn't need to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your attempt doesn't work because pattern rules with multiple targets and explicit rules with multiple targets are treated quite differently.

An explicit rule with multiple targets creates multiple explicit rules, one for each target.  But a pattern rule with multiple targets creates a single rule that [builds multiple targets](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Intro.html) as its output.  So your rule here:

```
foo/%.x foo/%.y: bar/$$*$$(suffix $$@)
        {complicated recipe}
```

actually tells make that a single invocation of `{complicated recipe}` will create both `foo/%.x` and `foo/%.y` targets.

I'm not sure what you  mean by *I can't do it in one line either* but you can always use a macro.  If you need multiple logical lines use the `define` syntax:

```
define complex_recipe
....
endef
```

In your comments you write *the `$$` duplication really makes the rules unwieldy* but the only reason you need that is because you're trying to define multiple pattern rules in one stanza.  If you write it multiple times you don't need any of that stuff:

```
define complex_recipe
...
endef

foo/%.x : bar/%.x ; $(complex_recipe)
foo/%.y : bar/%.y ; $(complex_recipe)
```

Speaking personally this would be my preference to how to write it rather than creating an external script or something like that.

Comment: What surprised me is I thought pattern rules only mean "both outputs produced at once" if `%` exists on the right-hand side... apparently that's not the case. But in any case, so is a macro (or identical calls to an external script) the only way? Is there no way to factor it out normally?

Comment: A pattern rule is defined by having `%` in the target (left hand side).  It's irrelevant whether there's a `%` in the right-hand side.  `%.x : foo ; ...` is a perfectly valid pattern rule.  A pattern rule is, by definition, creates a _pattern_ that matches how to build a target: it doesn't make sense to have a pattern rule where the target is not a pattern.

Comment: I don't know exaclty what you mean by "normally", but no, there is no way to define multiple pattern rules from a single "rule statement clause".  The closest you can get is to put the pattern rule into a variable with `define` then use `eval` to define it multiple times.

Comment: Sorry I didn't just mean "pattern rule" in general, and I meant `%` existing on the RHS *in addition* to LHS. I meant the 'simultaneous output' kind of pattern rule (idk if they have a name). It doesn't make sense to me for a pattern rule to be the 'simultaneous' kind if a `%` doesn't exist in the prerequisites because shouldn't the prerequisite have a say in whether the multiple outputs even *can* be created simultaneously? Two output names matching a pattern doesn't seem to carry enough information to tell whether there exists an input that can generate them both or not.

Comment: And by "normally" I meant without a macro (the `$$` duplication really makes the rules unwieldy). But I see, okay thanks.

Comment: Why would the prerequisites have any say?  A rule in make means, "if you want to build _target_ then here's a recipe that will build it".  The prerequisites are there only to determine if make _should_ rebuild the target or not, they have nothing to do with _how_ the target should be built.  In pattern rules it's slightly more complex because there can be multiple patterns that make could choose to build the same target; then which pattern is chosen depends on which prerequisites exist (for example, a `%.o` could be built from a `.c`, or `.cpp`, or `.F`, or whatever).

Comment: Remember even for pattern rules you don't have to list _all_ the prerequisites in the pattern.  Maybe you have a pattern rule `%.q : ; ...` then later you say `foo.q: 11.x` and `bar.q: 22.z`; that's perfectly fine, and changing that to `%.q %.r : ; ...` if the recipe builds multiple targets doesn't change anything WRT prerequisites.